# Solar Flux on Mars Surface

Tags: mars, interplanetary, solar-power, energy, the-sun

Considering that the Solar Flux on top of Mars' atmosphere is 590 W/m2 (following the 1/r^2 relation for sunlight), how much of this incident light actually arrives to Mars.

In other words, what is the value of the Solar Flux on Mars surface after it has been attenuated by the thin atmosphere of the planet? (I know it can also affected by landing site and time of the year, so a range of values is what I am expecting)

I'm trying to size Solar Arrays for a mission on Mars Surface and using 590 W/m2 doesn't seem suitable to me since I believe it represents the AM0 value.

Answer (score 6):

Where you are on the surface of Mars as well as the opacity of the atmosphere and various other effects will effect the result, but the below memo seems to show anywhere between **95 to 308 W/m²** (which is the daily mean beam irradiance).

The below link shows a memo from NASA with formulae.

Sources:

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19890018252.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where and when you are, 100-400W/m² - the authors of [this](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2017/ph240/black1/docs/nasa-tm-102299.pdf) caution that Mars' day is not of the same length as Earth's day, nor is Mars' year, which influences mean irradiance.

The big factors are the angle of light (where on Mars, and what time of Mars-day?), dust, atmosphere and season of Mars-year. There are a lot of helpful tables in the linked NASA paper.